# Can someone please provide me a pom.xml file for setting up karate framework for UI testing?

Tags: karate

I'm currently looking into karate-core, but I'm not sure whether I'm on the right path or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have a demo project you can reference on github. This would be a good place to check https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/examples/ui-test

Comment: I suggest you edit your answer with this link instead: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/examples/ui-test